# C# TreeView.EnsureVisible() - how else can I scroll?

Tags: c#, treeview

On my Treeview here: Left is TreeView before EnsureVisible(), and Right is After

The icon is neglected. I can't figure out how to show the icon after using EnsureVisible() and I would use an alternative to EnsureVisible() but i can't find any way to manually scroll. Is there? 
Maybe some NativeMethods with user32.dll or something ?

[image]

"Left: TreeView before EnsureVisible, and Right: After"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use a little external wizardry:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
//..

[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public static extern int GetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int SetScrollPos(IntPtr hWnd, int nBar, int nPos, bool bRedraw);

private const int SB_HORZ = 0x0;
private const int SB_VERT = 0x1;

 // bring your node into the display
someNode.EnsureVisible();

// now you can scroll back all the way to the left:
SetScrollPos(treeView1.Handle, SB_HORZ, 0, true);
// ..or just a few pixels:
int spos = GetScrollPos( treeView1.Handle, SB_HORZ);
SetScrollPos(treeView1.Handle, SB_HORZ, spos - 20, true);
```

Or you could do the whole scrolling with this function using the `SB_VERT` constant. You'd have to calculate the position in pixels for the chosen node, though, which may be a **pain**..

If you see flicker you should wrap the scrolling in a `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` block.

Comment: This did not work for me. It moves the scroll bar pos as I would expect, but the TreeView content (nodes) do not move back to the right, where they would be relative to the new scroll position. When I mouse click the scroll bar, the scroll bar gets repositioned to where it was previous to calling SetScrollPos.

Comment: I found [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10023/TreeView-without-right-scrolling) that uses a SendMessage method, which did work.